# Neo4j Granting Access Based on Label Patterns

Tags: neo4j, cypher, rbac

How can access be granted to a given user role, enabling them to retrieve (match) records if the labels contain a specific pattern in Neo4j?

While impersonating as a user and managing existing labels like Test, Test_1, and Test_2 in the database, is there a way to configure grant permissions ensuring that records with labels containing the prefix 'Test' are accessible to the user?

Answer (score 1):

When granting permissions based on node label / relationship type, you can specify all labels / types with `*`, or you can specify a list of label / type identifiers. But you can’t specify a pattern that would match the beginning of the label / type name.

See the [docs](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.4/administration/access-control/privileges-writes/#access-control-privileges-writes-create).

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is to give every node that has a label that starts with "Test" an additional shared label (say, "TestGroup"). Then you can just grant permissions to "TestGroup".

Comment: Thanks @cybersam, This works while reading, but I need to create these labels too..

Comment: True, and in addition to requiring more time to add the label to each node, an extra label will use up more storage and potentially more memory as well. Workarounds are always compromises.